# Replace Entire String In Dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I currently have a data frame resembling the below:

```
     ci_2 ci_2.01    ci_2.02 ci_2.03 ci_2.04 ci_2.05  
    <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>     
1 -215.   "-0.25905…" -252.   -254.   -254.   "-0.5771…" 
2  522.   "Error : …"  516.    520.    530.   "Error :…"  
3    0    "0"           0       0       0    "-67.768…" 
4   36.2  "Error : …"   36.2    35.2    33.8  "Error :…"   
5  -10.5  "-0.78985…"   -9.20   -3.67   -3.60 "-0.7723…"
```

Is there a way that would allow me to detect any string in a column and replace it with 0? I've seen examples with specific strings but was hoping for something more general.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think you need a regex here? Check the type of the column and if it is of type <chr>, assign all the values to an empty string.

Comment: When doing df[, 2], I get `FALSE` because `R` calls it a `tbl`. I don't want to replace every string in the column with `0`, since I still want the values that are provided outside of the sentences.

Comment: Sorry, you said you wanted to "detect any string", and now you say you "don't want to replace every string".

Comment: Sorry,  I see that the entire column is a column of strings. I meant the entries that state "Error..." rather than the strings with numbers, as I assume I can change those to numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove specific values, such as "Error etc.", across columns in a dataframe in `dplyr` like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~sub("^Error.*$", "NA", .)))
  ID  b  c d
1  1  x  9 7
2  2  y NA 7
3  3 NA  x 7
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                 b = c("x", "y", "Error:..."),
                 c = c("9", "Error: xyz", "x"),
                 d = c(7, 7, 7))
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, using data from @Chris Ruehlemann

```
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x) {
  x[grepl('Error', x)] <- NA
  x
})

#  ID    b    c d
#1  1    x    9 7
#2  2    y <NA> 7
#3  3 <NA>    x 7
```

`grepl` detects if any value has the word `'Error'` in it and replace it with `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3),
                        b = c("-0.25905…", -252., "66..66"),
                        c = c("-67.768…", "Error : …", "33.8"),
                        d = c(0, "9", 7)), 
                   class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                   row.names = c(NA, -3L))

library(data.table)
library(stringr)

setDT(df)

cols <- names(df)

# try to fix the numbers and have the as.numeric() fallback for where we fail to do so
df[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {
  as.numeric(stringr::str_replace_all(x, "[[:punct:][:alpha:]]+$", ""))
}), .SDcols = cols]

# not sure if it is legit to consider a true 0 value the same as a replaced "error" to zero
setnafill(df, type = c("const"), fill = 0)
```